# How would I get the latest outputted file from Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, opencv

Every 10 seconds, I capture a new image using my `igmcap()` function and store it in the direction folder `Captures`. I want my `identify()` function to run on the latest image captured. Is the best way to do this to wrap all of the functions inside of a single loop?

Python Code:

```py
def imgcap():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    framerate = cap.get(10)
    x=1

    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            # Our operations on the frame come here

            filename = 'Captures\\capture' +  str(int(x)) + ".png"
            x=x+1
            cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
            cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
            time.sleep(5)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            print("Ret False")

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

imgcap()


def identify(path):
    cmd = f"darknet.exe detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov4_test.cfg custom-yolov4-detector_best.weights -ext_output -out result.json {path}"
    # cmd = f"darknet.exe detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov4-tiny-custom.cfg custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_best.weights -ext_output -out result.json {path}"
    
    os.chdir(r'C:\Yolo_v4\darknet\build\darknet\x64')    
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.stdout.read()
    print(out)

identify(r'C:\\Yolo_v4\\darknet\\build\\darknet\\x64\\Captures\\SOMETHING_GOES_HERE')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your functions independent, `imgcap()` could return the actual path to the capture so it can be used for subsequent analysis:

```
def imgcap():
    # All your code goes here
    ...
    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return filename
```

If you are always going to run `identify()` on every new frame captured, it makes sense to make them part of the same loop, after the frame is saved.